# Defining a state of a failed SD cards by kernel tracing?

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, sd-card

I'm having a series of failing/sometimes failing SD cards. They either give one of the following `dmesg` outputs:

The completely dead ones (don't list at `/dev/mmcblk0`):

```
[  +0,000010] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card 
[  +2,819983] mmc0: card never left busy state
```

The failing ones (can occasionally still be mounted):

```
[Jun16 06:28] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[  +0,000339] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 00000 3.68 GiB 
[  +0,002835]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
[ +10,256689] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[ +11,264358] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[  +0,000016] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 7716736
[ +10,239972] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[  +0,000018] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 7716736
[  +0,000008] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 964592, async page read
[ +10,239931] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[  +0,000009] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 81792
[Jun16 06:29] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[  +0,000020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1066880
[ +10,240219] mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x900
[  +0,000011] print_req_error: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2101120
```

The best I've got with `error -110` is that it's a [timeout](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) of a sort, but tells very little on what actually happened with the SDCard.

**Background on how this came to be**

The SDcards end up in those states on some (seemingly random) of the embedded devices I'm working on, and I'm trying to understand if it's a matter of bad SD cards or if there might be something wrong with the controller driver that is pushing the cards to corruption.

About 5% of the cards have died completely, and I'm trying to see if that is to expect from the other ones.

I have tried to force the SDcard to reproduce the issue, but the ones under test (same brand, same type of device with same software) aren't showing any traces of wear after hundreds of GB of data written on them in a continuous manner as a part of the test. I use [stressdisk](https://github.com/ncw/stressdisk) for that.

I don't have a track of how often the device might of have abruptly lost  power, and the power supply is a regular 2A AC-DC adapter that is working ok for all the other needs of the device.

**Update**

The question seems to be suggested to be closed or answered in way that `helps me prevent failed SD cards in the future` as opposed to `using Linux to diagnose what is the current state of the SDcards`.

Let me try to rephrase then:

**What is the thoroughest way that you can analyze an SDcard failure on Linux?**

- Is it possible to enable debug logs for the MMC subsystem to get more info?
- What is a `card status 0x900`?
- Is it possible to sniff SD-bus or SD-bus communication from userspace to get indications that the card is starting to fail?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This seems more an hardware/use case problem than something else. I bet common sense might be  more important than Linux skills here. Are you doing heavy I/O in the cards, MySQL/Apache/compiling stuff...syslog/frequent system updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This seems more an hardware/use case problem than something else. I bet common sense might be more important than Linux skills here. Are you doing heavy I/O in the cards, MySQL/Apache/compiling stuff...syslog/frequent system updates? -- comment by Rui F Ribeiro

I can expand on the above.  But I agree with the first point, and I agree this was the first question to ask.

---

> - Should I enable some debug logs for the MMC subsystem?
> - Is there a userspace tool that can sniff what's going on?
> - How do I make the error codes make more sense?

The only confidence I've had from attributing failures has come more from the "history" and general results I get, not the specific errors from low-level commands.  Which are likely to vary between implementations anyway.

Even with an SSD, from a reasonable brand, I believe I've had [bad data returned](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1409874#c5) in place of I/O errors.  This has certainly been one of the known failure modes across many SSDs. [[2013](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/fast13/fast13-final80.pdf?wptouch_preview_theme=enabled)][[2017](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2992782&preflayout=flat)].  (Possibly surprising to people familiar with the contemporary filesystems and database implementations which often hope for a more manageable set of failure modes).  Notice that the papers I link here focused on the data returned; they did not make any more distinction in reported errors, except for the dead drive / bad sector distinction which you have already measured.

My SSD fault was on a "seller refurbished" laptop, which had already been "repaired" once, and was starting to show failures again - plausibly causing a power interruption to the drive just as in the linked papers.  It might also have failed to provide stable voltage levels.

> I'm trying to understand if it's a matter of bad SD cards or if there might be something wrong with the controller driver that is pushing the cards to corruption.

Good hardware with a good mains power supply doesn't tend to destroy a good SD card - *unless* you're putting too much load on it.  The workload is a very important variable<del>, which you did not [originally] mention</del>.  These memory cards are relatively small, usually cheap hardware that is designed for relatively un-demanding use storing media files (hence MMC, "MultiMediaCard").  Particularly cheaper ones won't necessarily be very good at "wear-levelling" (redistributing the load from hotspot logical blocks across a large number of physical blocks).

I have measured workload with a quick hack, scheduling a daily cron job to run `tunefs -l /dev/mmcblk0p4 | grep writes >> /var/log/writes.log`.

But if we set the workload aside, you'd be right to consider a possible controller-side issue from the information you gave so far.  I've had repeated bad sectors on an SD card due to writes from a pocket device, possibly when its battery was low.  This was a card from the one name brand.  The sectors were recoverable and I'm still using the same card.    I've also had some sort of transient initialization failure on this card, I *think* it was associated with bad sectors too (once I got past the initialization failure), but I could be mis-remembering.

> I'm having a series of failing/sometimes failing SD cards.

<del>The impression I get from your [original] question is that this is a small scale operation, and running a rigorous test matrix with different cards, controllers, and workloads would be overkill.</del>

After the workload, the first variable you control is the card.

Writing in 2018, there is one global name brand which can be considered "canonical" for sd cards -

see results at: https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=sd+card

- and you hopefully have a number of retail channels that can be considered... at least reliable enough for comparison purposes.  (Remembering that various popular online retailers act as "marketplace" as well as selling their own goods).

Official Raspbery PI hardware might also be acceptible.  I.e. SD cards, sold officially for running Linux on a small board computer, which have been reported to work well.  (Being a more demanding workload than media files).

As a broad brush, if you get a card that's faster than you strictly need, I also think of that as a potentially higher endurance rating.  (Given that speed rating tends to be much more available than endurance).

If you control / measure these two variables, then you can focus your judgements on the rest of the relevant hardware.

---

> The failing ones (can occasionally still be mounted)

Note, in the most general case, if you think a device has been badly written, you may attempt to clear this fault:

1. recover what data you can if desired
2. then stop trying to read bad blocks.  simply recreate the entire formatting (partition table + filesystem).
3. but if you're not sure and think the device might still be dying, you probably also want to test it.

If you have nice native MMC hardware like you do, you can use the Linux command `blkdiscard` as a more *efficient* way to test erasing all the blocks of the device, before you "reformat" it.  But efficiency is the only advantage, compared to testing for errors when overwriting the whole drive with zeros i.e. `dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0`.  (As well as avoiding any need to *write* the erased blocks, `blkdiscard` could also in theory provide a more "as-new" performance afterwards, and increase endurance, by giving the device a bit more freedom).

(If this was a  SATA drive - there is a dedicated "secure erase" command to discard the entire logical drive contents (see `man hdparm`).  However I am not aware of any equivalent MMC command.  Certain SSD vendors took advantage of this command to reset their block mapping tables, as a workaround for their failure to recover "as-new" performance with the equivalent `blkdiscard` sequence.  Note this command does *not* necessarily test a full-drive erase.  In some cases it will only erase an internal encryption key).

### Since you asked what my errors looked like

My SanDisk micro-SD card played up again recently.  It seems the specific errors below were due to flaky connection.  It was resolved by removing & re-inserting the micro-SD into the micro-SD to SD adaptor, after superstitiously blowing on all the metal pads.

In the reader on my Dell Latitude E5450 laptop (`sdhci-pci` kernel driver, Fedora Linux kernel version circa v4.17), it was failing to initialize the card.  On my SheevaPlug (same hardware and software details as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457293/sheevaplug-sdcard-slot-unable-to-allocate-bounce-cur-buffer)), this card seems to have been able to initialize but it showed IO errors.  Perhaps on the Dell the error-handling timeouts are not quite set up correctly.

Dell:

```
[    2.436566] mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems.
[    2.449019] mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:01:00.0] using ADMA
...
[509227.374012] mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
[509227.621510] mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
[509227.865472] mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
[509228.142120] mmc0: error -84 whilst initialising SD card
```

Sheevaplug:

```
[6076613.118617] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB 
[6076613.295811] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[6076613.545740] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[6076613.555301] mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
[6076613.728413] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 0, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[6076613.737965] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0
[6076613.912043] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 1, nr 7, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
[6076613.921599] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 1
...
```

Comment: `if you think a device has been badly written` What does `badly written` means?

I'm currently perceiving that you can have a good sector or a bad sector. If you ended up with a bad one, that isn't reparable from software any more.
You do seem to mention some third state `a repairable bad sector`. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer i.e. the interface provided by a modern block device: a bad logical block will repeatedly fail to read (checksum mismatch), but it is "repaired" if you successfully write new contents to it. Hence, if I believe my (non-smart) phone has corrupted my sd card again, all I need to do is reformat it. I don't even need to rewrite all the blocks (sometimes called "full format"): during & after a reformat, the filesystem will never read a block which it has not already written (there is never any reason for it to do so).

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer this is partly implemented using remapping tables; if there is a physical block which the drive concludes it should not rely on, it uses a different physical block instead. The drive starts off with a certain number of spare blocks. This is well-known for modern spinning hard drives.  I suspect similar SSD behaviour, to an extent, based on my experience. Given that SD cards implement wear-levelling (and some blocks will be known-bad at factory time), it seems most likely that at least some SD cards will behave the same.

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer and if your block device doesn't implement spare physical blocks, you can at least hope it still fits the model, by returning the same write error that devices would when there are no spares left :).

Comment: Is this what you said? :) `It takes a write to a logical block for a card to detect that the underlying physical sectors (associated with that logical block have failed). That is a trigger to assign the healthy sectors (if any available) to the logical block  and write to them.`

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer Not quite - it's quite happy to detect and report failure on a *read*.  But, if it went ahead and automatically "repaired" the logical block on a read - it would be returning a blank block and stopping the error from being reported. Silent errors are really really bad. So it does not "repair" the logical block until you deliberately overwrite it.

Comment: `I've also had some sort of transient initialization failure on this card` You saw this as an error printed by the kernel?

Comment: @TheMeaningfulEngineer yes. Something like your "completely dead ones", but I don't think I have the logs any more.  It's just failed again so I got some new ones for you at the very end of this answer... I really thought I remembered a transient init error, but for the moment it depends on the reader so I'm (hopefully) using the second reader to clear the fault.